# Recover an object on screen orientation change

Tags: android, reset, screen-orientation

In my code I created a card class; I show a bunch of cards later in a gridview. 
On screen orientation change I am loosing all the cards; with my previous question I was pointed in the right direction.

Now, what I have found in Android documentation and here in StackO is that

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(...);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    some_int_var = savedInstanceState.getInt(...);
super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
```

}

Now, I do that OK, since the Bundle object has several methods like putString, Char, etc. The primitives plus string that is.   But what about my cards? they are Card objects in a vector thus I can't use any of those methods.

How can I restore that vector WITHOUT using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance nor preventing the activity reset? In Android documentation it is advice to do this if there's heavy data to restart but that's not my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your own objects you can use `putParcelable()`

To make your object parcelable you should implement `Parcelable` and follow the following example to implement it.

http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.nl/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html

So:

```
public class ParcelData implements Parcelable {
    String name;

    ParcelData (Parcel source) {
        name = source.readString();
    }       

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
    }

    public class MyCreator implements Parcelable.Creator<ParcelData> {
        public ParcelData createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ParcelData(source);
        }
        public ParcelData[] newArray(int size) {
             return new ParcelData[size];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

first of all - you can pass with intent complex objects.

the why to do that is to make your class implement `Serializable` interface, or `Parcelable`,
and then use the `intent.getSerializableExtra(keyName);` or `intent.getParcelableExtra();`
`Serializable` is the easier to implement (basically declaring your class as implementing it is enough) but some specific classes cannot be serialized, while implementing `Parcelable` require a bit more work, but always possible.

other option - is holding the data you need to save in some singeltone class with getters and setters for save what ever you'd like to save, and use it anytime and anywhere in your code:
saving your data in the `onSaveInstanceState` method, and getting it back in `onRestoreInstanceState` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tried both and did work. What I did not understand was your las option: I still do the put and get using the bundle in OnsaVedInstanceState and restore; perhaps you meant something else?

Comment: @quinestor: my second option don't have anything with intents.  singeltone is a design pattern you should use if you'd like to have some class which only one instance of him can be created, and that instance is available from anywhere in your application. I recommend you to know exactly what singeltone is about, because it can be useful for lots of things.  you can read about it in this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern